In munchkin, can a combatant wait for all modifiers and then make a choice?
A combatant would currently lose a fight, asks the party if anyone is playing anything, they all say no.
Now if he plays a card to win the fight, can players now play monster modifiers?

From the rules

But note: someone may play a hostile  card on you, or use a special
power, just as you think you have won. When you  kill a monster, you
must wait a reasonable time, defined as about 2.6 seconds,  for anyone
else to speak up. After that, you have really killed the monster, and
you really get the level(s) and Treasures, though they can still whine
and argue.

That means, yes - they are still allowed to play a card, they can decide to play a card even after you cleared the monster and celebrated your victory. Always make sure to double tap so dead things stay dead.

I assume I can play in response to that as well?

Yes and you can take your time. For the active player the 2.6sec rule does not count. Since if you can't beat the monster, you still need to run away. As long as you didn't start running away, you can buff yourself. Or search for someone to help you.
